# gson\json deserialization error

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I want to parse a JSON object using GSON. Everything seems to work fine but when I'm trying to parse a more "complexed" object I'm getting a deserialization error. The object I'm trying to parse contains some primitives, a stack and a vector collection.

Is it possible that the stack\vector causing this problem? can I somehow over come this?

### The Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@4e76fba0 failed to deserialize json object [{"name_":"Human","points_":1,"alive_":true,"id_":0,"cssStyleClass":"pressed_p1"},{"name_":"Human","points_":0,"alive_":true,"id_":1,"cssStyleClass":"pressed_p2"}] given the type java.util.Vector<entities.Player>
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:64)
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:92)
    at com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.visitFieldUsingCustomHandler(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.ReflectingFieldNavigator.visitFieldsReflectively(ReflectingFieldNavigator.java:63)
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:120)
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonObject(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:76)
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:54)
```

### Request Code

```
Gson json = new Gson();
Multiplayer result = json.fromJson(answer.toString(), Multiplayer.class);
```

### Code On Servlet

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Multiplayer game = (Multiplayer)getServletContext().getAttribute("OnlineGame");
String responseStr = gson.toJson(game);

response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
out.write(responseStr);
```

### String from toString()

```
{serializeNulls:false,serializers:{mapForTypeHierarchy:{Map:MapTypeAdapter,Collection:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@596e1fb1,InetAddress:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DefaultInetAddressAdapter@4ce2cb55,Enum:EnumTypeAdapter},map:{Integer:IntegerTypeAdapter,URI:UriTypeAdapter,UUID:UuidTypeAdapter,BigInteger:BigIntegerTypeAdapter,URL:UrlTypeAdapter,Short:ShortTypeAdapter,Time:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DefaultTimeTypeAdapter@16bdb503,byte:ByteTypeAdapter,short:ShortTypeAdapter,Number:NumberTypeAdapter,double:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DoubleSerializer@b6e39f,GregorianCalendar:GregorianCalendarTypeAdapter,Calendar:GregorianCalendarTypeAdapter,Byte:ByteTypeAdapter,StringBuilder:StringBuilderTypeAdapter,Float:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$FloatSerializer@6719dc16,Locale:LocaleTypeAdapter,StringBuffer:StringBufferTypeAdapter,Date:DefaultDateTypeAdapter(SimpleDateFormat),Character:CharacterTypeAdapter,float:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$FloatSerializer@6719dc16,BigDecimal:BigDecimalTypeAdapter,Boolean:BooleanTypeAdapter,boolean:BooleanTypeAdapter,String:StringTypeAdapter,Timestamp:DefaultDateTypeAdapter(SimpleDateFormat),int:IntegerTypeAdapter,long:LongSerializer,Date:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DefaultJavaSqlDateTypeAdapter@52c05d3b,char:CharacterTypeAdapter,Double:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DoubleSerializer@b6e39f,Long:LongSerializer},deserializers:{mapForTypeHierarchy:{Map:MapTypeAdapter,Collection:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@596e1fb1,InetAddress:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DefaultInetAddressAdapter@4ce2cb55,Enum:EnumTypeAdapter},map:{Integer:IntegerTypeAdapter,URI:UriTypeAdapter,UUID:UuidTypeAdapter,BigInteger:BigIntegerTypeAdapter,URL:UrlTypeAdapter,Short:ShortTypeAdapter,byte:ByteTypeAdapter,Time:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DefaultTimeTypeAdapter@16bdb503,short:ShortTypeAdapter,Number:NumberTypeAdapter,double:DoubleDeserializer,Byte:ByteTypeAdapter,Calendar:GregorianCalendarTypeAdapter,GregorianCalendar:GregorianCalendarTypeAdapter,StringBuilder:StringBuilderTypeAdapter,Float:FloatDeserializer,Locale:LocaleTypeAdapter,StringBuffer:StringBufferTypeAdapter,Date:DefaultDateTypeAdapter(SimpleDateFormat),Character:CharacterTypeAdapter,float:FloatDeserializer,BigDecimal:BigDecimalTypeAdapter,Boolean:BooleanTypeAdapter,boolean:BooleanTypeAdapter,String:StringTypeAdapter,Timestamp:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DefaultTimestampDeserializer@5328f6ee,int:IntegerTypeAdapter,long:LongDeserializer,Date:com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DefaultJavaSqlDateTypeAdapter@52c05d3b,char:CharacterTypeAdapter,Double:DoubleDeserializer,Long:LongDeserializer},instanceCreators:{mapForTypeHierarchy:{SortedSet:DefaultConstructorCreator,Set:DefaultConstructorCreator,Queue:DefaultConstructorCreator,Collection:DefaultConstructorCreator,Map:DefaultConstructorCreator},map:{}}
```

Comment: Give an example of JSON that fails.

Comment: Post code, JSON, and stack trace. Otherwise no one can possibly help you (and this question will be closed).

Comment: Gson json = new Gson();
Multiplayer result = json.fromJson(answer.toString(), Multiplayer.class);

If I change it from "Multiplayer" to "gameboard" , it will work just fine (after a change on the servlet to send a "gameboard" type and not a "Multiplayer")

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what does answer.toString() returns. That is, the JSON value.

Comment: posted code, error and toString() output

Comment: Why are you using `Vector` instead of `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use an array `Player[]` instead of the generic collection `Vector<Player>`. It's not easy to use Java generics for serializing and deserializing. If you use an array instead, you will have no problem with it.

But it had been easier to answer if you show your code for `Multiplayer` and `Player`.

Comment: Multiplayer class<br/>
public class Multiplayer extends Game

Data members
private Vector<Player> players_; 
private int playersAlive_;

<br/>
Game class<br/>
public class Game

Data members
protected GameBoard board_;
protected boolean fromxml_;
protected String xmlpath_;
protected boolean active_;
protected int currentPlayer_;
Stack messageStack;


<br/>
Player class<br/>
public class Player 

Data members
protected String name_;
protected int points_;
protected boolean alive_;
protected int id_;
protected String cssStyleClass;

Comment: Jonas, Thanks for your answer, I posted the classes definition and its data members. Changing to Player[] will require too much of a code change at the moment, I will do it only if there is no other possibility.

Comment: @Shai: That is easy to change, and I recommend it, if you want to serialize it to Json.